# Unread notifications have the wrong link size

Tags: bug, design, usability

Unread notifications have large spacings on top and bottom. But they are not a part of the link and you can see default context menu when clicking them (also this area is not clickable):

> [image: скриншот неправильного контекстного меню]

Instead, to open a link in a new tab you have to click the other part of notification:

> [image: скриншот правильного контекстного меню]

It would be right to match link size with hightligh area.

[image: styles screenshot]

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9628/178988)

Comment: I just created an account on ru.so and the notification item height is not as tall as on your screenshots for me. Neither there, nor here. Are you using any browser extensions or css themes which could affect this?

Comment: @user1306322, note that height of new (unread) notifications differs from height of old (read) ones. The issue in only with new, on all sites.

Comment: can you provide comparative screenshots for normal and tall itmes with the non-linking areas selected or highlighted, and also see if you can figure out which class or id it has?

Comment: also what browser and OS version are you getting this on?

Comment: @user1306322, I'm using Chrome on Windows 7 and Windows 10, but that's irrelevant, I've added screenshot with styles.